# windows notification banner not visible

Tags: windows, push-notification

Does anyone know why the notification banner is not being shown when receiving two or more notifications with the same tag ?

The notifications are being created by a web page. When I have a single tab opened on the page the notification banner is being shown. When the page is loaded on two or more tabs the notification banner is not shown.

If the tag property is omitted windows will show a banner for every open tab.

The whole purpose of the tag attribute is to group notifications ...

is there any strategy to dispatch only one notification if the web page is opened in more tabs ?